# This Browserify-shim set-up not working with jquery-Mustache, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify, browserify-shim

The following setup gets a `jQuery` plugin `mixitup` working perfectly.

```
"browser": {
        "mixitup": "./app/bower_components/mixitup/src/jquery.mixitup.js",
        "jquerymustache": "./app/bower_components/jquery-Mustache/src/jquery.mustache.js"
    },
    "browserify": {
        "transform": [
            "browserify-shim"
        ]
    },
    "browserify-shim": {
        "mixitup": {
            "exports": "mixitup",
            "depends": [
                "jquery:jQuery"
            ]
        },
        "jquerymustache": {
            "exports": "Jquerymustache",
            "depends": [
                "jquery:jQuery",
                "mustache:mustache"
            ]
        }
    },
```

However, when I try to apply the same convention to `jquery-Mustache`, I am not able to get my templates fetch:

```
 "browser": {
   "jquerymustache": "./app/bower_components/jquery-Mustache/src/jquery.mustache.js"
  }
```

and

```
"jquerymustache": {
      "exports": "Jquerymustache",
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery",
        "mustache:mustache"
      ]
    }
```

I don't get an error from the terminal, (that would prove the `package.json` setup is kosher) but I do get this error from the console:

[image]

Which points to this:

[image]

This is my app.js file, feel this is the most relevant information:

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
var mixitup = require('mixitup');
var Jquerymustache = require('jquerymustache');
var mustache = require('mustache');
```

And the function which is fetching the template.

```
function templateLoader(e) {
        var doc = document,
            event = EventUtility.getEvent(e),
            target = EventUtility.getTarget(event);
        $.Mustache.options.warnOnMissingTemplates = true;

        $.Mustache.load('templates/index.html')
            .fail(function() {
                $('#overlay').append('Failed to load templates from <code>templates.htm</code>');
            })
            .done(function() {
                var output = $('#overlay');
                $('body').mustache('templateID');
            });
    }
```

And the file path for good measure, to prove the path in the function is correct:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like an issue with Browserify-shim, more like some kind of URL routing issue, though I guess by now you've solved it.

Comment: Actually I never did. Maybe I should try webpack?

Comment: Haha I went through the same trauma! I wouldn't go the webpack route, for me it was not up to the hype. At least using gulp/browserify you're just using JS which is modifiable...with webpack you have config and that's it. Hopefully one day a really easy solution will come through!

Comment: The reason I think it's a routing issue is that the 404 is happening before you even get to the `templateLoader` function...if you put a `debugger;` inside `templateLoader` does it even get tripped? Or inside that portion of `app.js`?